# How to use ModelState.SetModelValue() to set value of a List and get Model re-validated?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

My `Model` have a property which is a `List<int>`. In the UI it is a `Select2` autocomplete with multiple option set true. Since the `DefaultModelBinder` will not bind comma-separated values, the `ModelState.IsValid` always appears `false`.

I am using below code to set the value manually and get the `Model` re-validated. Now value has been changed to an empty `List<int>` from `null` but there should be items in it and the `ModelState` is also false.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Add(Contractor contractor, string OtherContactsIDs)
{
    ModelState.Remove("OtherContactsIDs");
    ModelState.Add("OtherContactsIDs", new ModelState());
    ModelState.SetModelValue("OtherContactsIDs", 
        new ValueProviderResult(OtherContactsIDs.Split(',')
            .Select(i => { return int.Parse(i); }).ToList(), 
            ValueProvider.GetValue("OtherContactsIDs").AttemptedValue, null));

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
```

What is the best way to achieve this?